# Using @angular/material with Angular 9 throws errors

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I've recently upgraded my app from Angular 8 to Angular 9.

Today I tried installing Angular Material. I followed the official instructions and used `ng add @angular/material` and then imported `MatChipsModule`.

But starting the application gives the following errors (yes I have tried removing node_modules and installing everything from scratch):

[image]

The above error is for MatAutoCompleteModule but I get the same error for all angular material modules.

I'm running Angular version 9.1.2 and Angular Material version 9.2.3.

My Angular Module where I import the Material Modules:

```
const contactsEffects = [
  ContactEffects,
  ContactSalesMeetingsEffects,
  ConsentsEffects,
  ContactSearchProfileEffects,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forFeature(contactsEffects),
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ModalModule,
    TooltipModule,
    ProgressbarModule,
    BsDropdownModule,
    TranslateModule,
    MomentModule,
    SkeletonScreenModule,
    ContactsRoutingModule,
    NguiMapModule,
    ActionListModule,
    CreateContactModule,
    ListComponentsModule,
    UiComponentsModule,
    ResourceModule,
    UtilModule,
    SidebarSharedModule,
    ContactActionsWidgetModule,
    HintModule,
    FormComponentsModule,
    AddContactToCallingListModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ContactCardDetailsComponent,
    CreateNoteComponent,
    ContactNextStepComponent,
    ContactActionsWidgetComponent,
    ContactOverviewComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ContactsComponent,
    ContactOverviewComponent,
    ContactActionsComponent,
    ContactNextStepComponent,
    ContactNextStepListItemComponent,
    ContactResidencesComponent,
    ContactResidenceComponent,
    ContactCardDetailsComponent,
    CreateNoteComponent,
    ProfileProgressModalComponent,
    ContactCardDetailsComponent,
    ContactSalesMeetingsComponent,
    ContactSalesMeetingsListItemComponent,
    ContactSalesMeetingsDetailCardComponent,
    ContactSalesMeetingsDetailEmptyComponent,
    ContactInfoRowComponent,
    ContactsSalesMeetingsNoEditModalComponent,
    ContactCardActionsComponent,
    CreateNewResidenceModalComponent,
    ContactOwnsResidenceComponent,
    ProfileResidenceMenuItemComponent,
    ContactCardDetailsLoadingComponent,
    ContactNextStepLoadingComponent,
    CallListModeHeaderComponent,
    ContactConsentsComponent,
    ConsentsListComponent,
    ConsentsSidebarComponent,
    ContactSearchProfilePageComponent,
    SearchProfileCardComponent,
    SearchProfileDetailsComponent,
    RelatedObjectsCardComponent,
    RelatedObjectItemComponent,
    SurveysModalComponent,
    NpsDetailsModalComponent,
    ContactTagsComponent,
  ],
  providers: [ContactOverviewEffects],
})
export class ContactsModule {}
```

Comment: Could we see your `app.module`?

Comment: @ChrisEdgington Just added the module (not app.module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my Angular and Material version were incompatible. For Angular version 9.1.2 I had to use angular/material version 9.1.0.